# Finding $P$ such that $A$ is diagonalizable and $D=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem statement:** I am given a matrix 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 1 \\
        1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
$$

I need to find a matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP=I$.

**Attempt:**
I have started with $C^{-1}AC=D$, where $C$ is the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues at the main diagonal, i.e. traditional diagonalization. I also know that since $A$ is positive-definite and so is $D$, I can multiply $D$ by $\sqrt{D}$ on both sides. This way I obtain $I$.

BUT when I'm modifying $C$, I am not getting the needed result. I know that the first step would be to normalize $C$ to make it have orthonormal columns, and then just multiply it by $\sqrt{D}$, but I don't have the desired result!

**Additional information:** $\lambda_1=3-\sqrt{2}, \lambda_2=3+\sqrt{2}, {e_1}^T=\begin{bmatrix}1-\sqrt{2} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, {e_2}^T=\begin{bmatrix}1+\sqrt{2} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is the Cholesky factorization.

Find a lower triangular $C$ such that $A = C C^T$.

There is a systematic procedure which performs well numerically, however in this case you can compute the answer directly:

Suppose $A>0$, and $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c\end{bmatrix} $ and we want to express in terms of the Cholesky factorization $C =\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ \beta & \gamma\end{bmatrix} $, then multiplying and equating gives
$\alpha = \sqrt{a}$, $\beta = { b \over \sqrt{a} }$ and $\gamma = \sqrt{c-{b^2 \over a}}$.

Substituting the numbers gives $C = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ { 1 \over 2} & {\sqrt{7} \over 2} \end{bmatrix} $.

If we replace $c,b$ above by appropriately dimensioned matrices, we can use the Schur complement to extend to higher dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please take a look at this question as well? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669645/interpreting-another-proposition-full-of-symbols

Comment: @Anonymous: I added an answer, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, your eigenvectors are not normalized - you need to do that before creating matrix $C$. Second, you need to divide, not multiply, by $\sqrt{D}$

$C^T A C = D^{1/2}D^{1/2}$
$(D^{-1/2})^T C^T A C D^{-1/2} = (CD^{-1/2})^T A (CD^{-1/2}) = 1$